# cannot find anything named

Tags: arrays, 2d, cell, processing

This is my first time with the error so I don't understand what it means. This code has been adapted from a tutorial online, which makes it more perplexing. In line 14, I get the error message "cannot find anything named 'innerGrid'". What is this referring to? To me the code has innerGrid well defined.

```
    //2d array
innerGrid [][] cell;

//number of columns
int col = 50;
//number of rows
int row = 10;

void setup()
{
  size(500, 100);
  background(0);
  //layout grid
  innerGrid= new cell[col][row]; //cannot find anything named 'innerGrid'
  //write columns (int i) and row numbers (int j) in counters
  for (int i = 0; i < col; i ++) 
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < row; i ++) 
    {
      innerGrid[i][j] = new innerGrid(i*10, j*10, 10, i+j);
    }
  }
  //create base layer
  initialGrid();
}

void initialGrid()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < cols; i ++ ) 
 {    
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j ++ ) 
    {
      innerGrid[i][j].display();
    }
  } 
}

void draw()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < cols; i ++ ) 
 {    
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j ++ ) 
    {
      innerGrid[i][j].updateColor();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: You should tag the language for more exposure and so reader know what language you are working with.

Comment: it's tagged, processing... is for processing.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are confused in this code...

to declare a variable you need to state the type of it, innerGrid is not a type, unless there is a class called this (classes by convention should have a capital first letter). Looks like what you are looking for is a double dimesion array of ints

```
int[][] innerGrid; // int is the type and innerGrid is the name of the var (array)
innerGrid = new int [dim1][dim2]// this also can be done in same line above...
```

But then you will find a lot of other problems as the class cell does not exist... in same line the

`= new cell[][]`

makes no sense unless there is a class 'cell' (no upper case... hummm) can't say. In that case the innerGrid array should be holding cell's instances, and be declared as this

`cell[][] innerGrid = new cell [rows][cols];`

The basic use is as follows:

```java
// declare a 2D array of ints
int[][] intArray = new int [10][20];

// declare a 2D array of Cell
Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell [10][20]; // note we didn't create any Celll yet
                                        //only an array to hold them
void setup(){
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i ++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < intArray[0].length ; j ++) {
    intArray[i][j] = i+j;
    cellArray[i][j] = new Cell();// here we creates the cells objects;
  }
} 

println("\n\n intArray: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i ++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < intArray[0].length ; j ++) {
    println(" intArray: ["+i+"]["+j+"] = " +  intArray[i][j]);
  }
} 

println("\n\n cellArray: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i ++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < intArray[0].length ; j ++) {
    println("cellArray: ["+i+"]["+j+"] = " +  cellArray[i][j]);
  }
} 
}




class Cell {
  float x;
  // a constructor
  Cell () {
    x = random(1);
  }

  String toString(){
    return nf(x, 2, 5);
  }
}
```